# Python Pig Latin to txt file

Tags: python, list, readfile

```
def main():

    pigFile = open('pigTest.txt', 'r')
    pigOut = open('pigOut.txt', 'w')

    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

    pigList = getWords(vowels, pigFile)

    t = translate(pigList, vowels)
    print(pigList)
    print("Converted: ", t)

    w = write(t, pigOut)
    pigFile.close()

def getWords(vowels, file):

    data = file.read().split()

    return data
def translate(pigList, vowels):
    newPigList = []

    for word in pigList:
        if word[0] in vowels: # if the first index of the first word is a vowel
            newPigList.append(word + "way") #add to new list
        else: #if letter does not begin with vowel
            newPigList.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")

    return newPigList

def write(pigList, pigOut):
    pigOut.write(" ".join(pigList))

main()
```

output:

```
['if', 'beast', 'student', 'away']
Converted:  ['ifway', 'eastbay', 'tudentsay', 'awayway']
```

**problem: 'awayway' should be on a new line in the output since in pigTest.txt it's on a new line**

My program pushes all of the text onto the first line, when it should be put on the correct line, and I'm not sure how to solve it

My txt file looks like this

```
if beast student 
away
```

Comment: please rewrite your question. Start with your problem statement and goals. Then add what you tried yourself already.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to process the input line by line. One way to do this is to call `pigFile.readlines()` and iterate over the lines that it returns.

```
def main():
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
  pigFile = open('pigTest.txt', 'r')
  pigOut = open('pigOut.txt', 'w')
  for line in  pigFile.readlines():
    pigList = line.split()
    t = translate(pigList, vowels)
    print("Input: ", pigList)
    print("Converted: ", t)
    w = write(t, pigOut)
  pigFile.close()

def translate(pigList, vowels):
  newPigList = []

  for word in pigList:
    if word[0] in vowels: # if the first index of the first word is a vowel
      newPigList.append(word + "way") #add to new list
    else: #if letter does not begin with vowel
      newPigList.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay") 

  return newPigList

def write(pigList, pigOut):
  pigOut.write(" ".join(pigList))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand `str.join` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).
You want:

```
"\n".join(pigList)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:-

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
with open('file2.txt') as f, open('pigOut.txt', 'w+') as out:
    newPigList = []
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        line = line.split()
        newPigList.append(map(lambda x: x+'way' if x[0] in vowels else x[1:] + x[0] + "ay", line))     
    print newPigList
    for data in newPigList:
        out.write(str(data)+'\n')
    out.seek(0)
    print out.read()
```

Output:-

```
[['ifway', 'eastbay', 'tudentsay'], ['awayway']]
['ifway', 'eastbay', 'tudentsay']
['awayway']
```